# How do I get TinyMCE Advanced working in Wordpress?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, tinymce

Here is an image which shows the site I'm working on: [Link to how the current editor looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9fmY.jpg)

I'm doing some maintenance and conversion on a wordpress site.  My client is not fluent in HTML, and wants to be able to edit pages in a WYSIWYG fashion.  However, this option does not exist in the current editor.  (see image)

I have installed TinyMCE Advanced as per the instructions, it appears in my plugin list (also in the image), and activated the plugin, but I'm not seeing any changes.  Is there a *base* TinyMCE plugin I need to install first?  I was under the impression that Wordpress came pre-installed with it.

Some more info:

- This is Wordpress 3.4.2
- The TinyMCE plugin (if there is one) does *not* appear in the plugin list.
- I do not know if there is an option in any panel where you choose which

Is it also possible to simply add the button to the current TinyMCE configuration?  Any assistance would be appreciated.  Thanks,

-Tom